# Ngrx 8: How to mock multiple selectors returning different value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx

I'm writing unit tests for the angular 8 component whose dependency is a ngrx store. I've multiple selectors in `ngOnInit` function. I would like to mock those selectors using `overrideSelector` method.

Currently, I'm facing the following issues:

1. if I try to access the state selector using overrideSelector like this `mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getAuthData, authenticationData);` it's expecting an argument for the selector and throwing error as,
   `No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 3, '(selector: string, value: AuthData): MemoizedSelector<string, AuthData, DefaultProjectorFn<AuthData>>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(state: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Overload 2 of 3, '(selector: MemoizedSelector<any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>, value: any): MemoizedSelector<any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(state: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MemoizedSelector<any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>'. Type '(state: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'MemoizedSelector<any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>': release, projector, setResult Overload 3 of 3, '(selector: MemoizedSelectorWithProps<any, any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>, value: any): MemoizedSelectorWithProps<any, any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(state: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps<any, any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>'. Type '(state: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'MemoizedSelectorWithProps<any, any, any, DefaultProjectorFn<any>>': release, projector, setResultts(2769)`
2. If try to set the state using mockStore.setState() function it's not changing the state and I'm getting error as,
   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'authData' of undefined`

**Here's the code:**

home.page.ts:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {
  getSubscribedReports,
  getSelectedSchedule,
  getSelectedSummary,
  getName,
  isUserAuthenticated
} from '@app/store/directory.reducer';
import { filter, first } from 'rxjs/operators';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscribedReports$: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedSchedule$: Observable<any>;
  summary$: Observable<string>;
  showSearch: boolean;
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  selectName$: Observable<any>;
  isUserAuthenticated$: Observable<boolean>;


  constructor(
    private store: Store<any>,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isUserAuthenticated$ = this.store.select(isUserAuthenticated);
    this.subscribedReports$ = this.store.select(getSubscribedReports);
    this.selectedSchedule$ = this.store.select(getSelectedSchedule);
    this.selectName$ = this.store.select(getName);
    this.summary$ = this.store.select(getSelectedSummary);

    this.getSubscribedReports();
  }

  getSubscribedReportsorts() {
    // some operations
  }



  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

}
```

home.page.spec.ts:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, flush, flushMicrotasks, TestBed, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx";
import { ModalController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from "@ngrx/store/testing";
import { HomePage } from "./home.page";
import { AppState, directoryReducer, initializeState } from "@app/store/directory.reducer";
import * as fromDirectory from '@app/store/directory.reducer';
import { AuthData, SelectedPortSchedule, SubscribedReports } from "@app/providers/directory.model";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Store, StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import {
    authenticationData, 
    subscribedReportsData,
    selectedPortScheduleData,
 } from "@testData/home.page.testData.ts"


fdescribe("HomePage", () => {
    let component: HomePage;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;
    let el: DebugElement;
    let storeMock: any;

    let mockStore: MockStore<{directory: AppState}>;
   
    
    
    let initialState = initializeState();
    let storeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ['select', 'dispatch']);
    let modalCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ModalController', ['create']);
    let geoLoactionSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('GeoLocation', ['getCurrentPosition']);

    beforeEach(async() => {
        storeMock = {
            dispatch: jasmine.createSpy('dispatch'),
            select: jasmine.createSpy('select')
          };


        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [HomePage],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
                StoreModule.forRoot({ directory: directoryReducer })
            ],
            providers: [
                provideMockStore(),
                // { provide: Store, value: storeSpy },
               
                { provide: ModalController, value: modalCtrlSpy },
                { provide: Geolocation, value: geoLoactionSpy }
            ],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);

        

        fixture.detectChanges();

        
    });
    
    beforeEach(() => {
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        mockStore.setState({
            directory: {

                ...initialState,
                authData: authenticationData,
                subscribedReports: subscribedReportsData,
                selectedPortSchedule: selectedPortScheduleData,
                selectedPortScheduleSummary: selectedPortScheduleData.summary,
            }

        });
        mockStore.refreshState();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getAuthData, authenticationData);
        mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getSubscribedReports, subscribedReportsData);
        mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getSelectedSchedule(selectedScheduleData), selectedScheduleData);
        mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getPortName, (ports: any) => (id: string) => ports.find(port => port.id == id));
        mockStore.overrideSelector(fromDirectory.getSelectedSummary(selectedScheduleData.summary), selectedScheduleData.summary );
        mockStore.refreshState();
        // await fixture.whenStable();
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it("should create the page", () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should verify user is authenticated", () => {
        let isUserAuthenticated: boolean;
        component.isUserAuthenticated$.subscribe(data => isUserAuthenticated = data);
        expect(isUserAuthenticated).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should load subscribed reports", () => {
        component.subscribed$.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('subscribed reports: ', data);
        })
    })
});
```

**Please help me to solve this issue!**

Comment: Why is the first beforeEach async? Your overrideSelectors calls might kick in before mockStore received a value.

Comment: Even if I remove the async from first beforeEach, I'm still getting error as,
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'authData' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

your selector you are mocking expects `(selector: string, value: AuthData)` as parameters but the mock you've provided has the signature `(state: any)`